# What happens if I have two servlet mappings in web.xml that match a request?

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets

What happens if I have two servlet mappings in web.xml that match a request? Does it choose most specific?

For example if I have the following xml and a request comes to ..../something while it go to somethingservlet or everything_else servlet?

```
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>something</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/something</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>    

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>everything_else</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Having a servlet on `/*` is by the way a strange design. Perhaps it should actually be a filter?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First succesful match will be used.

There are certain mapping rules follwed by servlet container. Read Servlet 2.5 specification chapter SRV.11:

> The path used for mapping to a servlet is the request URL from the request
>       object minus the context path and the path parameters. The URL path mapping
>       rules below are used in order. The first successful match is used with no further
>       matches attempted:
>
> 1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the path of the servlet. A successful match selects the
>      servlet.
> 2. The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done
>      by stepping down the path tree a directory at a time, using the ’/’ character as
>      a path separator. The longest match determines the servlet selected.
> 3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp), the servlet
>      container will try to match a servlet that handles requests for the extension.
>      An extension is defined as the part of the last segment after the last ’.’ character.
> 4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the container will
>      attempt to serve content appropriate for the resource requested. If a "default"
>      servlet is defined for the application, it will be used.