# Angular 4 and Java BackEnd Project in a single WAR

Tags: java, angular, jboss, dev-to-production

I created a angular 4 project and using JAVA REST API Project as a BackEnd. I need that I can move my angular 4 project as a staic content inside JAVA war file.

I created the production build for angular project and copy the files from dist folder and paste it inside webcontent of java project. I am able to read the index file of angular project but other files are giving 404.

Please help how can I move my angular project inside my java project to get a single war file for production.

[image: Project Structure::]

WEB.XML :-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>userInformation</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.newgen.ap2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.newgen.ap2.CrossOrigin</param-value>
 </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Stultuske so that I have single war for production.any other good approach you are having then please suggest.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915379/how-to-setup-angular-4-inside-a-java-war-project or this one https://github.com/marco76/java-demo

Comment: These both are with Maven but i don't want to use maven...

Comment: @NishantVarshney yes, I understand the what, it's the why that baffles me. you are sure you want to change the deployment of your backend each time you change a label in your UI? There's not even a reason they should have to run on the same server, let alone the same war file

Comment: @Stultuske I get your point... But I am having only JBOSS App Server so I am not having any way to deploy the angular 4 project on it. That's why i am going for this approach.

Comment: paste your web.xml and if possible the structure of your webcontent

Comment: I'd still recommend you read @TimeTraveler answer in the linked article - he explains things you need to do so the angular files are found - regardless of using maven.

Comment: Hii Guys.. I done the thing... Now only issue is that I am not able call the background images used in css... It is not taking the image path from root directory....

Comment: @suenda... I posted what you asked...

Answer (score 0):

Change your web.xml to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>userInformation</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.newgen.ap2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.newgen.ap2.CrossOrigin</param-value>
 </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The idea is to use a different Servlet to serve your static resources.

Here are some more SO posts that might be helpful:

[Servlet filters' order of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086712/servlet-filters-order-of-execution)

[How are Servlet url mappings in web.xml used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385596/how-are-servlet-url-mappings-in-web-xml-used)

[What happens if I have two servlet mappings in web.xml that match a request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872973/what-happens-if-i-have-two-servlet-mappings-in-web-xml-that-match-a-request)