# Java Servlet HTTP Status 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-405, servlet-mapping

I'm working on a Java Servlet Web Application where I want to create a login for the management. For that, I used mapping `/management/login` to render the login page and the same route to post the login request. Both use the same `LoginController` but I have defined `doGet` and `doPost` methods there. `doGet` works fine but when I hit login it also comes to `doPost` method but renders,

```
HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed
Type: Status Report

Message: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Description: The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.

Apache Tomcat/10.1.8
```

I just want to render the error message below the login form.

I referred to a couple of Stack Overflow answers, but none of them are working for me.

Below is my code,

**LoginController.java**

```java
public class LoginController extends ControllerBase {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (isAuthenticated(req)) {
            res.sendRedirect("/management/dashboard");
            return;
        }

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/views/management/login.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");

        if (Utils.isNullOrEmpty(email) || Utils.isNullOrEmpty(password)) {
            req.setAttribute("error", "Invalid credentials");
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/views/management/login.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(req, res);
            return;
        }

        login(req);
        Console.log("User logged in");
        res.sendRedirect("/management/dashboard");
    }
}
```

**Login.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<t:public_layout>
    <jsp:attribute name="title" trim="true">Management Login</jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body>

        <div class="container p-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h4>
                        Management Login
                    </h4>
                    <p>
                        Welcome back! Sign in to your account to access all the features.
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <form action="/management/login" method="post">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com"
                                         autocomplete="username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"
                                         autocomplete="current-password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Sign in</button>
                        </div>

                        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    ${error}
                            </div>
                        </c:if>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </jsp:body>
</t:public_layout>
```

**web.xml**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HomeController</servlet-name>
        <display-name>HomeController</display-name>
        <description>HomeController</description>
        <servlet-class>com.dinindu.oas.controller.HomeController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ManagementController</servlet-name>
        <display-name>ManagementController</display-name>
        <description>ManagementController</description>
        <servlet-class>com.dinindu.oas.controller.management.ManagementController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ManagementLoginController</servlet-name>
        <display-name>ManagementLoginController</display-name>
        <description>ManagementLoginController</description>
        <servlet-class>com.dinindu.oas.controller.management.LoginController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ManagementDashboardController</servlet-name>
        <display-name>ManagementDashboardController</display-name>
        <description>ManagementDashboardController</description>
        <servlet-class>com.dinindu.oas.controller.management.DashboardController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LogoutController</servlet-name>
        <display-name>LogoutController</display-name>
        <description>LogoutController</description>
        <servlet-class>com.dinindu.oas.controller.LogoutController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HomeController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern/>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ManagementController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/management/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ManagementLoginController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/management/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ManagementDashboardController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/management/dashboard</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LogoutController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/assets/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[image]

Comment: In fact, exact matches take precedence: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872973/what-happens-if-i-have-two-servlet-mappings-in-web-xml-that-match-a-request

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this part

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ManagementController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/management/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ManagementLoginController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/management/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Url pattern `/management/*` matches the request url `/management/login` and occurs prior the servlet mapping of `ManagementLoginController` servlet in web.xml. Hence `ManagementController` is the servlet responsible for processing of the request.

Here's an extract from Servlet 2.5 specification chapter SRV.11:

> The path used for mapping to a servlet is the request URL from the
> request object minus the context path and the path parameters. The URL
> path mapping rules below are used in order. The first successful match
> is used with no further matches attempted:
>
> 1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the path of the servlet. A successful match selects the
>    servlet.
> 2. The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done by stepping down the path tree a directory
>    at a time, using the ’/’ character as a path separator. The longest
>    match determines the servlet selected.
> 3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp), the servlet container will try to match a servlet that handles
>    requests for the extension. An extension is defined as the part of the
>    last segment after the last ’.’ character.
> 4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the container will attempt to serve content appropriate for the
>    resource requested. If a "default" servlet is defined for the
>    application, it will be used.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah, I saw the rules from @tgdaies comment. As I can understand, Java Servlet cannot handle child routes properly. Correct? :(

Comment: @0xdw I believe it can, you just need to put the servlet-mappings in order of their specificity(more specific first). In your case you should put ManagementLoginController mapping before ManagementController mapping